# How can I edit the data of a table with Symfony?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, symfony, jqgrid, reactjs

In my symfony application, I am rendering many views with in the form of a table.

I'd love to edit those data by clicking on the table cells, filling new data, and saving it dynamically.

I've explored jqGrid, DataTable with jEditable but none offer simple way to integrate with jquery.

I've ended up building my own view with a form that replaces a tr line when clicking on a table row but that super custom and now that I need to use the same behaviour for other element, I feel a bit discouraged.

Is there a Symfony best practice ? Is that the job or an Angular or React ? What should I do ?

My dream solution would be something that would know which entity field is being edited, edit it and validate the entity before returning a result.

My custom code :

```
{% extends ':Template/Backend:backend.html.twig' %}

{% block title_wrapper %}
    <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="inline-block">Coûts d'achat</h2>
            <span id="header_buttons" class="pull-right">
                <a href="{{ path('user_supplier_select') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-white">Ajouter un fournisseur</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    <p>Assignez des fournisseurs à vos ingrédients. Vous pourrez ensuite paramétrer le coût d'achat.</p>
    <p>L'unité utilisée pour la quantité minimale d'achat est l'unité que vous utilisez pour gérer votre stock. Essayez d'adopter la même que votre fournisseur.</p>


    {{ form_start(parameter_cost_form, {'attr' : {'id' : 'parameter_cost_form'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(parameter_cost_form) }}
    {{ form_stylesheet(parameter_cost_form) }}
    {{ form_javascript(parameter_cost_form) }}


    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="DataTable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="editable" >
        <colgroup>
            <col span="3">
            <col span="1" style="min-width: 80px !important">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ingrédient</th>
            <th>Marque</th>
            <th title="Quantité disponible dans un produit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Packaging</th>
            <th title="Quantité payée qui divisera le prix pour obtenir le coût par unité" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Quantité</th>
            <th title="Unité utilisée pour calculer le coût de revient" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Unité</th>
            <th title="Montant payé pour la quantité donnée dans l'unité donnée" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Montant HT (€)</th>
            <th title="Quantité minimale d'achat en nombre de produits - permet d'arrondir les commandes à la quantité minimale servie par votre fournisseur" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Q d'achat minimale</th>
            <th>Fournisseur</th>
            <th title="Référence qui sera indiquée dans les bons de commande" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Référence fournisseur</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="edit_form" style="display: none;" class="child_collection">
                {# Data-repo and data-id are used for updating the unit fields #}
                <td class="name" data-repo="AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\UserIngredient"></td>
                <td class="brand"></td>
                <td class="packaging"></td>
                <td class="quantity">
                    {{ form_widget(parameter_cost_form.quantity) }}
                    {{ form_errors(parameter_cost_form.quantity) }}
                </td>
                <td class="unit-control">
                    {{ form_widget(parameter_cost_form.unit) }}
                    {{ form_errors(parameter_cost_form.unit) }}
                </td>
                <td class="numberObjects">
                    {{ form_widget(parameter_cost_form.numberObjects)  }}
                    {{ form_errors(parameter_cost_form.numberObjects)  }}
                </td>
                <td class="minimumBuyingQuantity">
                    {{form_widget(parameter_cost_form.minimumBuyingQuantity)  }}
                    {{form_errors(parameter_cost_form.minimumBuyingQuantity)  }}
                </td>
                <td class="userSupplier">
                    {{ form_widget(parameter_cost_form.userSupplier)  }}
                    {{ form_errors(parameter_cost_form.userSupplier)  }}
                </td>
                <td class="supplierReference">
                    {{ form_widget(parameter_cost_form.supplierReference)  }}
                    {{ form_errors(parameter_cost_form.supplierReference)  }}
                </td>
                <td class="action buttons">
                    {{ form_widget(parameter_cost_form.submit) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% set i = 0 %}
        {% for ingredient in user_ingredients %}
            {% for uis in ingredient.userIngredientSuppliers %}
                {% set i = i + 1 %}
                <tr id="ingredient_{{ i }}" data-userIngredientId="{{ ingredient.id }}" data-userIngredientSupplierId="{{ uis.id }}" class="table_row">
                    {# Data-repo and data-id are used for updating the unit fields #}
                    <td class="name" data-id="{{ ingredient.id }}">{{ ingredient.getProductName }}</td>
                    <td class="brand">{{ ingredient.getProductBrand }}</td>
                    <td class="packaging">{{ ingredient.getProductPackaging }}</td>
                    <td class="quantity">{{ uis.quantity }}</td>
                    <td class="unit-control" data-value="{{ uis.unit.id }}">{{ uis.unit }}</td>
                    <td class="numberObjects">{{ uis.getLastNumberObjectValue }}</td>
                    <td class="minimumBuyingQuantity">{{ uis.minimumBuyingQuantity }}</td>
                    <td class="userSupplier" data-value="{{ uis.userSupplier.id }}">{{ uis.userSupplier }}</td>
                    <td class="supplierReference">{{ uis.supplierReference }}</td>
                    <td class="action buttons">
                        <a href="{{ path('user_ingredient_supplier_delete', {'userIngredientSupplier' : uis.id }) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-white fmu_delete_button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        {#<a href="#/" class="btn btn-xs btn-white add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>#}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% else %}
                {% set i = i + 1 %}
                <tr id="ingredient_{{ i }}" data-userIngredientId="{{ ingredient.id }}" data-userIngredientSupplierId="" class="table_row empty">
                    {# Data-repo and data-id are used for updating the unit fields #}
                    <td class="name" data-id="{{ ingredient.id }}">{{ ingredient.getProductName }}</td>
                    <td class="brand">{{ ingredient.getProductBrand }}</td>
                    <td class="packaging">{{ ingredient.getProductPackaging }}</td>
                    <td class="quantity"></td>
                    <td class="unit-control"></td>
                    <td class="numberObjects"></td>
                    <td class="minimumBuyingQuantity"></td>
                    <td class="userSupplier"></td>
                    <td class="supplierReference"></td>
                    <td class="action buttons">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-white fmu_delete_button" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        {#<a href="#/" class="btn btn-xs btn-white add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>#}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Ingrédient</th>
            <th>Marque</th>
            <th>Packaging</th>
            <th>Quantité</th>
            <th>Unité</th>
            <th>Montant HT (€)</th>
            <th>Q d'achat minimale</th>
            <th>Fournisseur</th>
            <th>Référence fournisseur</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </div>

    {{ form_end(parameter_cost_form) }}

    {% import ':Model/Macros:_macros.html.twig' as macros %}
    {{ macros.jqueryui_dialog('.fmu_delete_button', "Confirmation", 'Etes-vous sur de vouloir supprimer les informations de ce produit ?', 'Oui, supprimer', 'Non, annuler') }}

    <script>
        $(function(){

            var $editForm = $('#edit_form');
            var $parameterCostForm = $('#parameter_cost_form');

            $('#editable').on('click', 'td:not(:last-child)', function(){
                var $parent = $(this).parent();
                if ($parent.attr('id') == 'edit_form') {
                    return;
                }
                $($editForm.data('previous')).show();
                $editForm.insertAfter($parent);
                $parent.hide();
                $editForm.data('previous', '#' + $parent.attr('id'));
                $parameterCostForm.data('name', $parent.find('.name').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.help-block').remove();
                $editForm.find('.form-control').attr('style', 'position:absolute !importante;');
                $editForm.show();

                $parameterCostForm.attr('action',  '{{ path('parameter_cost') }}/' + $parent.attr('data-userIngredientId') + ($parent.attr('data-userIngredientSupplierId') ? '/' + $parent.attr('data-userIngredientSupplierId') : ''));

                $editForm.find('.name').eq(0).attr('data-id', $parent.find('.name').eq(0).attr('data-id'));
                $editForm.find('.name').eq(0).html($parent.find('.name').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.brand').eq(0).html($parent.find('.brand').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.packaging').eq(0).html($parent.find('.packaging').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.quantity').eq(0).find('.form-control').val($parent.find('.quantity').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.unit-control').eq(0).find('.form-control').val($parent.find('.unit-control').eq(0).attr('data-value'));
                $editForm.find('.numberObjects').eq(0).find('.form-control').val($parent.find('.numberObjects').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.minimumBuyingQuantity').eq(0).find('.form-control').val($parent.find('.minimumBuyingQuantity').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.userSupplier').eq(0).find('.form-control').val($parent.find('.userSupplier').eq(0).attr('data-value'));
                $editForm.find('.supplierReference').eq(0).find('.form-control').val($parent.find('.supplierReference').eq(0).html());
                $editForm.find('.name').eq(0).trigger('initiated');
            });

            {# Data-repo and data-id are used for updating the unit fields #}
            var updateRow = function(){
                $editForm.find('.form-control').each(function(){
                    var $previous = $($editForm.data('previous'));
                    var thisClass = $(this).closest('td').attr('class');
                    var $eq = $previous.find('.' + thisClass).eq(0);
                    $previous.addClass('edited');

                    if (thisClass == 'unit-control' || thisClass == 'userSupplier') {
                        $eq.html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
                        $eq.attr('data-value', $(this).val())
                    } else {
                        $eq.html($(this).val());
                    }
                })
            };

            $editForm.on('change', '.form-control', updateRow);

            $('body').on('click', '#parameter_cost_form button[type="submit"]', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                var formData = new FormData($parameterCostForm[0]);

                console.log($parameterCostForm.attr('action'));
                $editForm.data('sent', $editForm.data('previous'));

                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'post',
                    url         : $parameterCostForm.attr('action'),
                    data        : formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false
                }).done(function(response){
                    response = JSON.parse(response);
                    if ($editForm.data('previous') == $editForm.data('sent')) {
                        $editForm.find('td:nth-child(n+4)').remove();
                        var $substitutes = $(response.view).find('td');
                        $editForm.append($substitutes);
                        updateRow();

                        if (response.success) {

                            var $previous = $($editForm.data('previous'));
                            if ($previous) {
                                $previous.attr('data-userIngredientSupplierId', response.id).removeClass('edited');
                                $parameterCostForm.attr('action', response.action);
                                console.log(response.action);
                                var $action = $previous.find('.action a').eq(0);
                                if ($action.attr('href') == false) {
                                    $action.attr('href', '{{ path('user_ingredient_supplier_delete') }}' + '/' + response.id);
                                    $action.show();
                                }
                            }
                            $.fn.logMessage('success', "L'ingrédient '" + $parameterCostForm.data('name') + "' a été enregistré.");

                        } else {
                            $.fn.logMessage('error', "L'ingrédient '" + $parameterCostForm.data('name') + "' n'a pas pu être enregistré. Vérifiez la validité des données renseignées.");
                            $editForm.find('.form-control').attr('style', 'position: relative !important;');
                        }

                    } else {
                        var $sent = $($editForm.data('sent'));
                        $('#parameter_cost_form button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                        if ($sent) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                $sent.removeClass('edited');
                                $.fn.logMessage('success', "L'ingrédient '" + $sent.find('.name').eq(0).html() + "' a été enregistré.");
                            } else {
                                $.fn.logMessage('error', "L'ingrédient '" + $sent.find('.name').eq(0).html() + "' n'a pas pu être enregistré. Vérifiez la validité des données renseignées.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }).fail(function(){
                    $.fn.logMessage('error', "L'ingrédient '" + $parameterCostForm.data('name') + "' n'a pas pu être enregistré. Vérifiez la validité des données renseignées.");
                });

            })
        });

    </script>

    {{ macros.javascript_json_prefill('initiated', '#edit_form .name') }}


    <style rel="stylesheet">
        .unit-control {min-width: 40px;}
        #edit_form td:nth-child(n+4) {
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        #edit_form .form-control, #edit_form .btn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
            border: 0;
        }
        .edited {
            background-color: #fffec9 !important;
        }
    </style>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I developed something like this a while back, since I couldn't find anything good for it. What I did was create a mapping from form fields to columns using dom attributes. then Using Jquery I would replace the values for columns with those fields, when a specific button on a row was clicked, and then send them using another button.This way you can actually use the same action you use for handling the form elsewhere, and you can use a symfony form.

Comment: I just read what you've already done, In order to get around the **multiple rows** problem you're facing, render the form somewhere else and hide it, and each time the edit button on each row is clicked replace the fields in that row with the form fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the exact same requirements some months ago. And I have been able to successfully integrate [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) with `Symfony 2.7` .

For this, I used a Symfony bundle called [thrace datagrid bundle](https://github.com/thrace-project/datagrid-bundle). The bundle can be a little tricky to use but once figured it makes things really easy. Other plugins that you mentioned deteriorate in terms of performance (browser crash, etc) with increasing number of rows. Whereas you can modify the twig for modifying jqGrid and it will behave as you want it to overcome the *Symfony* limitations.

All I take from the thrace datagrid bundle is the `json` array that it returns. I have been able to completely customize the frontend which includes operations like **editing data, adding new data, saving changes, and many more.** 
I have created grids with more than 30 columns and they are working just fine so that should answer your concern about having huge views and being able to edit them. jqGrid provides all sort of data validation which you can provide in the frontend itself.

I will suggest giving jqGrid (the bundle) one more shot with Symfony. I can definitely help you out with the integration of jqGrid and Symfony.

Comment: only one contributor, it's not really reassuring... were you able to use your own  symfony forms?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by forms? If you need to edit/display the data you can just create the entity and Thrace will take care of the rest.

Comment: well, symfony forms help you validate data before it's sent, it allows building select fields easily, etc. I'm not sure how thrace would provide all those nice options

Comment: You can provide basic frontend validation on the frontend through js/jquery. Also Thrace handles the back end validation too according to your entity definitions. That's the most validation I have ever needed on the backend. Are you looking for something more specific than that?

Comment: well, I would need to give it a try. I need validation and it seems ok, I need specific controls in the grid (like checkboxes, selects, etc) and I need callbacks on events principal actions

Comment: Yes checkboxes, select, datepicker, filter toolBar,  etc and many more are all possible with jqGrid. You definitely can give it a try. If you find any problems post it here and link it in the comments here (if I don't see your question) and I will definitely help you out.